# Removing the Water Tight-ness property from the mesh constructed by poisson reconstruction using Point Cloud Library

Tags: mesh, surface, point-cloud-library, poisson, 3d-reconstruction

I would like to generate visually appealing surface reconstruction from the the point clouds.

I am using point cloud library. I tried creating a mesh using poisson reconstruction method but later found that it gives a water tight reconstruction.

For example: In my case I have a point cloud of a room

Using the code at http://justpaste.it/code1 , I was able to get a reconstruction like this

[image: pic 1]
<sub>(source: [pcl-users.org](http://www.pcl-users.org/file/n4033883/snapshot00.png))</sub>

The above picture has the surface which is covering the top view. This was visualized using MeshLab.
Then later on the MeshLab GUI when I press points, it looks like this.
[image: pic 2]
<sub>(source: [pcl-users.org](http://www.pcl-users.org/file/n4033883/snapshot01.png))</sub>

But in the second picture there are points on its surface too(Not clearly visible in the attached picture).

Can you help in creating a model that has no points on the top and just has the inside structure ?

Any other suggestions to improve the reconstruction quality ?

The point cloud of the room and generated ply file can be downloaded from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95042389/temp_pcd_ply_files.tar.bz2

Answer (score 2):

One solution that works for me is obtaining a convex/concave hull of your point cloud. Then you can use this hull to filter/crop your mesh after Poisson reconstruction. If you use the PCL you can try `ConvexHull` or `ConcaveHull` together with `CropHull` and test the results. Hope this solves your issue, it did for me.

Comment: How do you crop a PolygonMesh?
The CropBox/CropHull filter only seem to accept PointClouds and not a mesh?

Comment: You should preferably ask a new question regarding this

Answer (score 1):

As far as my experience is concerned (meshing caves), meshing with Poisson will result in watertight model/mesh, which is why your model was covered entirely. I only deal with meshes using MeshLab but I am guessing it is the same thing. What I did try is using Ball-Pivoting meshing algorithm in MeshLab which result in non-watertight model. Maybe that is what you are looking for.